# Spring MVC : Not possible to modify the value of beanpropertybindingresult 's autogrowcollectionlimit when to use the @ @InitBinder

Tags: spring-mvc

[image]Spring version : 4.1.7

When we use the `@InitBinder`, it's not possible to modify the value of beanpropertybindingresult's autogrowcollectionlimit. (Default value 256).
The `binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(4096);` modify correctly the value of `WebDataBinder`'s `autogrowcollectionlimit`, but not the value of beanpropertybindingresult's autogrowcollectionlimit.
We try to use binder.initBeanPropertyAccess(); but we received the following error :

**"DataBinder is already initialized - call initBeanPropertyAccess before other configuration methods"**

```
@InitBinder
public void registerBeanEditors(WebDataBinder binder) throws TacException {
        binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(4096);
        binder.initBeanPropertyAccess();
}
```

Could you tell me how to assign the new value (4096) to beanpropertybindingresult's autogrowcollectionlimit  please

regards

Comment: We migrated to version Spring 4.3.5 to solve this issue.

Comment: Fix : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/1266/commits/9f229283fb4690aee347d22aae5f4625a8576746